# Method "AddCustomList" for Object"_Application failed

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting an Error with 1004, searched it already many times but couldnt found an answer. Maybe I have too long list.
I have orders and I want to sort the Orders for the Weeks (KW means Week).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim vSortList As Variant
vSortList = Array("?", "KW1 2022", "KW2 2022", "KW3 2022", "KW4 2022", "KW5 2022", "KW6 2022", "KW7 2022", "KW8 2022", "KW9 2022", "KW10 2022", "KW11 2022", "KW12 2022", "KW13 2022", "KW14 2022", "KW15 2022", "KW16 2022", "KW17 2022", "KW18 2022", "KW19 2022", "KW20 2022", "KW21 2022", "KW22 2022", "KW23 2022", "KW24 2022", "KW25 2022", "KW26 2022", "KW27 2022", "KW28 2022", "KW29 2022", "KW30 2022", "KW31 2022", "KW32 2022", "KW33 2022", "KW34 2022", "KW35 2022", "KW36 2022", "KW37 2022", "KW38 2022", "KW39 2022", "KW40 2022", "KW41 2022", "KW42 2022", "KW43 2022", "KW44 2022", "KW45 2022", "KW46 2022", "KW47 2022", "KW48 2022", "KW49 2022", "KW50 2022", "KW51 2022", "KW52 2022" _
& "KW1 2023", "KW2 2023", "KW3 2023", "KW4 2023", "KW5 2023", "KW6 2023", "KW7 2023", "KW8 2023", "KW9 2023", "KW10 2023", "KW11 2023", "KW12 2023", "KW13 2023", "KW14 2023", "KW15 2023", "KW16 2023", "KW17 2023", "KW18 2023", "KW19 2023", "KW20 2023", "KW21 2023", "KW22 2023", "KW23 2023", "KW24 2023", "KW25 2023", "KW26 2023", "KW27 2023", "KW28 2023", "KW29 2023", "KW30 2023", "KW31 2023", "KW32 2023", "KW33 2023", "KW34 2023", "KW35 2023", "KW36 2023", "KW37 2023", "KW38 2023", "KW39 2023", "KW40 2023", "KW41 2023", "KW42 2023", "KW43 2023", "KW44 2023", "KW45 2023", "KW46 2023", "KW47 2023", "KW48 2023", "KW49 2023", "KW50 2023", "KW51 2023", "KW52 2023")
    
Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=vSortList
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Sort key1:=[F2], Header:=xlYes, ordercustom:=Application.CustomListCount + 1
End Sub
```

Can someone say where is my misstake?
If I run it, it comes an Error with debugging, if I click there the

```
Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=vSortList
```

is yellow

Comment: I suspect you have too many items in your array. If you simply format the week number to always use 2 digits, you wouldn't need to do this at all.

Comment: @Rory I did it now, like you said. Instead of KW1 KW01, KW02.. so on. But there is now the problem with the years. He Ordered me now like this KW32 2024, KW32 2025, KW40 2023 but it isnt the correct order with year

Comment: Sorry, that was dim of me. You'd also need the year first - eg `2024 KW32` - is that an option?

Comment: @Rory ahah no all fine, thanks for your help. :) If there is no other way, ofc it could be an option as well. Ill try it soon. Thanks

Comment: Not sure if there may be something else wrong as your code runs fine in empty sheet?
Are you sure the list doesn't already exist?